# How to add columns to a file based on matched column and maintain the order of lines using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I match a column from a file to next file and append the columns if present using awk.

File 1:

```
T36
T200
T77
T99
T100
T101
T110
```

File2:

```
T36 aa  123
T36 aa  456
T200 cc 789
T99 aa  1011
T77 bb  1213
T77 bb  1415
T100 xx 1617
```

Desired output:

```
T36 aa  123
T36 aa  456
T200    cc  789
T77 bb  1213
T77 bb  1415
T99 aa  1011
T100    xx  1617
T101
T110
```

In my output file I want to get the order of file 1 and also print the lines that are not present in file 2.

So far I have done this  but it is printing only the matched columns not all.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1]=$1; next} { print x[$1], $0 }' file1 file2
```

Please Help!

Comment: (1) you have to parse `file2` first and later `file1` (2) You have to save multiline string for every key, that means appending to exisitng value, (depending on a conditional expression) and not overwriting (3) when printing, again a ternary is needed because you want to print the key if there is no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'f==2 {map[$1] = ($1 in map) ? map[$1] ORS $0 : $0} 
     f==1 {print (($1 in map)? map[$1] : $1)}
' f=2 file2 f=1 file1
```

or the same using the `FNR==NR` idiom:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$1] = ($1 in map) ? map[$1] ORS $0 : $0; next} 
     {print (($1 in map)? map[$1] : $1)}
' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
T36 aa  123
T36 aa  456
T200 cc 789
T77 bb  1213
T77 bb  1415
T99 aa  1011
T100 xx 1617
T101
T110
```

Comment: Thanasisp, thank you, this worked but in some cases it is repeating lines

Comment: Are lines into file1 unique? In any case, you have to update with a reproducible case where "it is repeating lines" so I can check it. Now I can only see the test example into your question.

Comment: Thank you yes they are unique, I can change them manually. Its not too many. Thank you so much for your help.